# tdplotsetrotatedcoords function is working on axes but not on drawn arcs (circle)

Tags: tikz-3dplot

According to [tikz-3dplot documentation](https://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf), `tdplotsetrotatedcoords` should rotate features following the suite of Euler angles rotations:

> **Description:**
>
> Generates the style `tdplot_rotated_coords` which provides the coordinate transformation for rotated coordinate frame within the current main  coordinate  frame, based on user-specified  Euler angles (α,β,γ). Rotations use the z(α)y(β)z(γ) convention of Euler rotations, where the system is rotated by γ about the z-axis, then β about the (world) y-axis, and then α about the (world) z-axis.
>
> **Syntax:**
>
> `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{α}{β}{γ}`

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\tdplotdrawarc[green]{(O)}{.8\radius}{0}{360}{}{}

\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{10}{30}{70}
\tdplotdrawarc[red]{(O)}{\radius}{0}{360}{}{}

\draw[thick,color=blue,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) --(.7,0,0) node[anchor=north]{$x’$};
\draw[thick,color=blue,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) --(0,.7,0) node[anchor=west]{$y’$};
\draw[thick,color=blue,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) --(0,0,.7) node[anchor=south]{$z’$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

is rendered as:

[image: Resulting drawing]

However, the red circle is always on the same xy-plane as the original unrotated green circle.

I expected it to be rotated into the x'y'-plane.

How to achieve that properly?
The `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords` function seems not to work.

Comment: You can post your question [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex). (And you **can have** an good answer.)

Comment: @s.k At https://topanswers.xyz/tex, nickname marmot answer all questions about 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have to enclose the circle drawing into a '[scope](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/scopes/)', but for the axes it's not the case:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\tdplotdrawarc[green]{(O)}{.8\radius}{0}{360}{}{}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{10}{30}{70}
% Scope enclosing here:
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
  \tdplotdrawarc[red]{(O)}{\radius}{0}{360}{}{}
\end{scope}

\draw[thick,color=blue,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) --(.7,0,0) node[anchor=north]{$x’$};
\draw[thick,color=blue,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) --(0,.7,0) node[anchor=west]{$y’$};
\draw[thick,color=blue,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) --(0,0,.7) node[anchor=south]{$z’$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]